# Continuous function and quasi-isometry

Tags: gr.group-theory

I have a problem. I don't know if every continuos function is necessarily a quasi-isometry. I was trying to prove that, but failled for now. I also can't find a counterexample. If you have any hints, i would be very happy if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Continuous functions from where to where? And what is your definition of quasi-isometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $f(x) = \exp(2\pi i x)$ is continuous, yet not a quasi-isometry.

The map from the open semicircle $(\-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(\theta) = \tan(\theta)$ is a homeomorhpism, but not a quasi-isometry.

Any map (not necessarily continuous) between compact sets is a quasi-isometry.

Answer (score 0):

And how can you prove the last statement about compact spaces. I already thought about that, but was able to establish onl one side of the inequality in the definition of quasi-isometry.

Comment: Which side of the inequality? Both sides are proven using the same argument. 